# Download nuspec via NuGet v3 API

Tags: artifactory, nuget-server

Artifactory seems to be missing the [`PackageBaseAddress` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource).

Is there another way to download the `nuspec` file for a given NuGet package version?

I need some metadata from the `nuspec` and want to avoid downloading the entire `nupkg` for that.